# Calling a function from a sub in VBA - qualifier error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to be more "object oriented" in my VBA code. However, I am having trouble passing variables through to functions. Here, I get an invalid qualifier error message on the `IsEmpty` function.

How can I correct my code?

```
Sub test_too_much_data()

If toomuchdata("Data input", "B1018") = False Then
    MsgBox ("Sorry, the tool can only accomodate 1000 rows.")
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


Function toomuchdata(sheet As String, range As Variant) As Boolean
    toomuchdata = IsEmpty(Sheets("String")).range(range)
End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tested the code in my answer below? any feedback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `Function` code to something like below:

```
Function toomuchdata(sheetStr As String, RngStr As String) As Boolean
    toomuchdata = IsEmpty(Sheets(sheetStr).Range(RngStr).Value)
End Function
```